# Get the following error => ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a subscription inside a component which closes a modal just like the following:

```
this.subscription.add(
  this.deletingSuccess$.subscribe((r) => {
    this.params.closeCallback();
  })
);
```

upon component destroy I call the following:

```
 ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

The next time I call

```
const options: ModalDialogOptions = {
      viewContainerRef: this.viewContainerRef,
      context: { content: data },
      ios: {
        presentationStyle: 5,
      },
};
this.modalService.showModal(CustomerModalComponent, options);
```

I get the following error => ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges.

Can someone please help me out. spend 8 hours on this

Comment: Show more of your common component, where you call showModal function. Or would be great to have reproduced situation on stackblitz.